# Dynatrace Managed with JMeter: How to see the HEADERS(passed in JMETER) in the Dynatrace Managed

Tags: performance, jmeter, integration, dynatrace

I have this requirement to integrate JMeter with Dynatrace managed. I have given the headers in the JMeter with the required info.
Since I am new to Dynatrace managed, I am unable to figure out how to see the JMeter requests and filter them out on the basis of Headers.

Can someone please guide me on this?

Answer (score 2):

In JMeter you can add HTTP Headers using [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager/)

[image]

In Dynatrace you can monitor these headers as:

[image]

More information: [Dynatrace and JMeter integration](https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/setup-and-configuration/integrations/third-party-integrations/test-automation-frameworks/dynatrace-and-jmeter-integration)